# Hide Vim fold characters

Tags: vim

When using Vim to write prose my folds look like this:

```
+ # Section A expanded
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
| sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
| Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
| nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
| reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
| pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
| culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

+ # Section B folded
+ # Section C folded
```

I like the `+` markers, but I find the `|` distracting. Is is possible to remove the pipes? I'd like things to look like this:

```
+ # Section A expanded
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
 nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
 reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
 pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
 culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

+ # Section B folded
+ # Section C folded
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appearance of the *fold column* (`:help fold-foldcolumn`) is fixed and cannot be changed; you'd have to modify Vim's sources and recompile. You can only use the

```
:highlight FoldColumn ...
```

command to adapt the visual appearance of it as a whole (e.g. by choosing different colors, lower contrast, to make this information less distracting).